# Getting an error where illegal unit of measure in a subfigure

Tags: errors

The error is in the second subfigure getting a unit error being treated as zero i am doing the same in another example with no issues

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FreeBot1.png}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:FreeBot1}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hskip
 \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FreeBot2.png}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:FreeBot2}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FreeSN.png}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:FreeSN}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{(a) and (b) FreeBOT \cite{9341129} (b) FreeSN \cite{9811583}}
```

\end{figure}enter code here

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`\hskip` is a tex primitive that should not appear in latex but needs a length to say how much space to add. `\hskip 2cm` but you probably meant `\hfill`